# How to draw irregular 3d shapes in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, shapes

I would like to draw the cylinder-like irregular shape displayed below using Ti*k*Z.

[image: Irregular 3d shape]

I know how to plot regular cylinders using Ti*k*Z, however the commands I know don't apply for irregular 3d shapes, as the one shown in the picture. Suggestions and comments are welcome! Thanks a lot.

Comment: \path plot[smooth] coordinates{...}; and adjust the tension as needed.